# [ROS2] msg stamp time difference

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to assess if the msg is too old by comparing current time and the msg time stamp.

```
rclcpp::Time time_now = rclcpp::Clock().now();
double dt = (time_now - trajectory_buf_->header.stamp).nanoseconds();
```

However, the application crashes with "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  can't subtract times with different time sources"

Alternatively, I tried it this way:

```
std_msgs::msg::Header::_stamp_type time_now = rclcpp::Clock().now();
double dt = (time_now - trajectory_buf_->header.stamp).nanoseconds();
```

This one doesn't compile with "no match for ‘operator-’"

What is the right way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321436/%5Bros2%5D-msg-stamp-time-difference/) by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-04-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-19**:\

> ```
> can't subtract times with different time sources
> ```

I believe the issue here is not that the *types* of `time_now` and `trajectory_buf_->header.stamp` are different, it's that the *value* they contain came from a different time source (see [Clock and Time/Clock/ROS Time Source](https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html#ros-time-source) for some background).

**Comment by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) on 2019-04-19**:
the *trajectory_buf* message is being stamped in another node using `rclcpp::Clock().now()` call, that I'm also trying to use here. I don't see how the source is different. I looked through the article you mentioned, but didn't find the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to get the clock from your node instance (`my_node.get_clock()`) , otherwise it does not have a valid time source and that's why your datatypes don't match.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vadbut](https://answers.ros.org/users/39907/vadbut/) on 2019-04-19**:
can you please explain what is the difference between "rclcpp::Clock().now()" and my_node.get_clock() ? I used the "rclcpp::Clock().now()" across all my nodes to stamp messages and it worked fine before I came across this problem. Switching to get_clock() indeed solved the problem, but I would like to figure out what is the difference between the methods.

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2020-08-01**:
bump. I would also like this comment answered

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-08-01**:
The static method in roscpp takes advantage of global state that's setup by roscpp:::init. This useage of global state has been removed in ROS 2 allowing truly running separate nodes in the same process. But as such you need to explicitly connect things like clocks to the Node instance that you care about.